# Is it possible to integrate TinyMCE text editor into an Android app?

Tags: php, android, html, forms, android-studio

I tried looking for an answer but I couldn't find any.

I have a simple TinyMCE text editor that stores data into a MySQL database and then displays it on the website.

I would like to know if it is possible to display that text in and Android app using exactly the same formatting.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you do you means by "display that text in an Android app".

I've just scanned the TinyMCE text editor you mentioned. Look like it is a library created for web application only. So If you want to integrate it as a mobile native component - aka View, the answer is No.

But in mobile development, we have a thing called WebView. both Android and Ios have it. Basically, it is a mini version of a browser. So you could have a web page that contains your TinyMCE text editor. Next, create a mobile application that has a WebView. Then present your web page on that WebView.

According to this doc, you must add some tag to present the editor on mobile.
https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/mobile/